# Sha256 and Biginteger in java and C# are getting different values

Tags: c#

Actually i have a java code whic i need to convert to c#

```
salt="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";


MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
messageDigest.update(salt.getBytes());
result=new BigInteger(messageDigest.digest());
```

> ```
> result = -8679331902525424680818339047284551675590913508739318217139721412571178967790
> ```

and the c# code which i am using

```
rawData = "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";

using ( SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
{             
 var Rawdatabytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rawData);
 byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Rawdatabytes);              
 var result = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(bytes);
}
```

> ```
> result = 8306751456257555796593622157661757526221618682565362023319192974333645213676
> ```

for both after converting to Biginteger getting different result
any guess?

Comment: Java and C# have different and incompatible BigInteger binary representations. That said, I think you should use `Byte[]` instead of `BigInteger` for working with hashes.

Comment: actually i need to convert the result to Biginteger that is the requirement.

Comment: You should check if salt.getBytes() returns the same as System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rawData)